# Navbar dropdown width resize

Tags: html, css, navigation, width, navbar

I have a navigation bar that is fluid on both desktop and mobile devices. However, the drop-down items widths don't resize based on the parent's width. I would like to hover over a drop-down item and it has the same width as the list item I hovered over. At the moment it has a fixed width but I can't seem to get it working by trying other options. I also cannot get the entire navigation bar to center, as at the moment it is stuck to the left. Thanks for the help!

Here's a codepen of the code: https://codepen.io/Macast/pen/rYQPNe

HTML:

```
<nav>
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/J.-Freeman-&-Son-Landscape-Logo-White.png">
        </div>

        <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Short +</label>
                <a href="#">Short</a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1" />
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our Aim</a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>
            <li>
                <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Dropdown Even Longer +</label>
                <a href="#">Dropdown Even Longer</a>
                <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2" />
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->
                        <label for="drop-3" class="toggle">More Options +</label>
                        <a href="#">More Options</a>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="drop-3" />

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
    display: none;
}
/* Giving a background-color to the nav container. */

nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #254441;
}
#logo {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    /*padding: 0 30px;*/
    /*float: left;*/
    /*font-size: 20px;*/
    /*line-height: 60px; */
}
#logo img {
    width: 30%;
}
/* Since we'll have the "ul li" "float:left"
 * we need to add a clear after the container. */

nav:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
/* Removing padding, margin and "list-style" from the "ul",
 * and adding "position:reltive" */

nav ul {
    /*float: right;*/
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
/* Positioning the navigation items inline */

nav ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    background-color: #254441;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Styling the links */

nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #000000;
}
/* Background color change on Hover */

nav a:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
}
/* Hide Dropdowns by Default
 * and giving it a position of absolute */

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
    top: 60px;
}
/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: inherit;
}
/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */

nav ul ul li {
    width: 170px;
    float: none;
    display: list-item;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Second, Third and more Tiers 
 * We move the 2nd and 3rd etc tier dropdowns to the left
 * by the amount of the width of the first tier.
*/

nav ul ul ul li {
    position: relative;
    top: -60px;
    /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */

    left: 170px;
}
/* Change ' +' in order to change the Dropdown symbol */

li > a:after {
    content: ' +';
}
li > a:only-child:after {
    content: '';
}
/* Media Queries
--------------------------------------------- */

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    #logo {
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
    }
    #logo img {
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    nav {
        margin: 0;
    }
    /* Hide the navigation menu by default */
    /* Also hide the  */

    .toggle + a,
    .menu {
        display: none;
    }
    /* Stylinf the toggle lable */

    .toggle {
        display: block;
        background-color: #254441;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 17px;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .toggle:hover {
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    /* Display Dropdown when clicked on Parent Lable */

    [id^=drop]:checked + ul {
        display: block;
    }
    /* Change menu item's width to 100% */

    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    nav ul ul .toggle,
    nav ul ul a {
        padding: 0 40px;
    }
    nav ul ul ul a {
        padding: 0 80px;
    }
    nav a:hover,
    nav ul ul ul a {
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    nav ul li ul li .toggle,
    nav ul ul a,
    nav ul ul ul a {
        padding: 14px 20px;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    nav ul li ul li .toggle,
    nav ul ul a {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
    /* Hide Dropdowns by Default */

    nav ul ul {
        float: none;
        position: static;
        color: #ffffff;
        /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
    }
    /* Hide menus on hover */

    nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: none;
    }
    /* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */

    nav ul ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    nav ul ul ul li {
        position: static;
        /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 330px) {
    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 94%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tell me, if you declare the following styles `position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;` on `nav ul ul`, then *remove* the explicit `width` declared on `nav ul ul li`, do you get the expected behaviour? Also, make sure you declare `position: relative` on the containing element `nav ul li`

Comment: Removing the width on nav ul ul li just shrinks the width to the size of the text in each of the list items, and not the dropdown parent's width. I have updated the code with your adjustments and the problem still remains: https://codepen.io/Macast/pen/rYQPNe

Comment: Did you declare `left: 0; right: 0;` on `nav ul ul` (as I advised) - or did you just remove the width from `nav ul ul li`? See a practical demonstration here: https://codepen.io/UncaughtTypeError/pen/yPQZja (your CodePen forked)

Comment: I don't see any of the adjustments I've recommended in your "updated codepen". Even the `width` for the dropdown list items are still explicitly defined. Are you *sure* you have updated it? Maybe you missed it, but better to refer instead to the forked pen I included in my previous comment to observe the adjusted behaviour. (https://codepen.io/UncaughtTypeError/pen/yPQZja)

Comment: My apologies, I updated it but it must not have saved correctly or I had forgotten to do something simple (I've only used CodePen once before). That does work now, thank you so much!

Comment: The only thing I also couldn't seem to get to work was centering the nav bar content to the middle of the screen. At the moment it is on the left side but I can't seem to push them into the middle. Any ideas?

Comment: I've added the solution as an official answer, explaining the fix applied and how/why it works, with an embedded code snippet demonstrating it and a horizontally centered `.menu`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To adjust the dropdown menu size to the same size as the containing list-item, declare a `left` and `right` property value of `0` on the dropdown element in question (`nav ul ul`), then remove the explicitly declared `width` on the nested list items of the dropdown menu (`nav ul ul li`).

**Example:**

```
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    /* additional property values declared */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

This works because the dropdown menus are *already positioned `absolute`* **and** the containing parent element list item (`nav ul li`) is *already positioned `relative`*.

You can position `absolute` elements *relative* to their parents if their parents are `relative`.

So all we are doing here is defining the extent of the dropdown menu width to "stretch" from "left to right" of the *parent's width*.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
    display: none;
}
/* Giving a background-color to the nav container. */

nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #254441;
}
#logo {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    /*padding: 0 30px;*/
    /*float: left;*/
    /*font-size: 20px;*/
    /*line-height: 60px; */
}
#logo img {
    width: 30%;
}
/* Since we'll have the "ul li" "float:left"
 * we need to add a clear after the container. */

nav:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
/* Removing padding, margin and "list-style" from the "ul",
 * and adding "position:reltive" */

nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
/* Positioning the navigation items inline */

nav ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #254441;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
/* Styling the links */

nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #000000;
}
/* Background color change on Hover */

nav a:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
}
/* Hide Dropdowns by Default
 * and giving it a position of absolute */

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
    top: 60px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: inherit;
}
/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */

nav ul ul li {
    /*width: 170px;*/
    float: none;
    display: list-item;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Second, Third and more Tiers 
 * We move the 2nd and 3rd etc tier dropdowns to the left
 * by the amount of the width of the first tier.
*/

nav ul ul ul li {
    position: relative;
    top: -60px;
    /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */
    
    left: 170px;
}
/* Change ' +' in order to change the Dropdown symbol */

li > a:after {
    content: ' +';
}
li > a:only-child:after {
    content: '';
}
/* Media Queries
--------------------------------------------- */

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    #logo {
        display: block;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
    }
    #logo img {
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    nav {
        margin: 0;
    }
    /* Hide the navigation menu by default */
    /* Also hide the  */
    
    .toggle + a,
    .menu {
        display: none;
    }
    /* Stylinf the toggle lable */
    
    .toggle {
        display: block;
        background-color: #254441;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 17px;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .toggle:hover {
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    /* Display Dropdown when clicked on Parent Lable */
    
    [id^=drop]:checked + ul {
        display: block;
    }
    /* Change menu item's width to 100% */
    
    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    nav ul ul .toggle,
    nav ul ul a {
        padding: 0 40px;
    }
    nav ul ul ul a {
        padding: 0 80px;
    }
    nav a:hover,
    nav ul ul ul a {
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    nav ul li ul li .toggle,
    nav ul ul a,
    nav ul ul ul a {
        padding: 14px 20px;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    nav ul li ul li .toggle,
    nav ul ul a {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
    /* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
    
    nav ul ul {
        float: none;
        position: static;
        color: #ffffff;
        /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
    }
    /* Hide menus on hover */
    
    nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: none;
    }
    /* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
    
    nav ul ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    nav ul ul ul li {
        position: static;
        /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 330px) {
    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 94%;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav>
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="images/J.-Freeman-&-Son-Landscape-Logo-White.png">
            </div>

            <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                    <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Short +</label>
                    <a href="#">Short</a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1" />
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Aim</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                    <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Dropdown Even Longer +</label>
                    <a href="#">Dropdown Even Longer</a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2" />
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->
                            <label for="drop-3" class="toggle">More Options +</label>
                            <a href="#">More Options</a>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="drop-3" />

                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Option</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

**In Addition:**
You can horizontally center the navigation menu by removing the `float` rule declared on nested list-items (`nav ul li`), as this will negate any attempt to align content (unless you use `flex-box`), then declare `text-align: center` on the containing unordered list (`.menu`), as demonstrated below:

```
nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for explaining it all too, not just showing code without explanation like some other contributors do. Thanks again!

Comment: @Macast I appreciate a fellow stack-overflower who appreciates an answer with meat on the bones that takes time to flesh out.